# i want to output my average with a comma and decimal values like x,xxx.xx in sql

Tags: mysql, decimal

I want to output my average value with a comma, like:

> x,xxx.xx

Currently, I am getting my output as `1,295` but I need to include decimal places like `1,295.17`. What's going wrong?

```sql
SELECT 
  Format(
    Avg(
      Abs(
        a - (
          SELECT 
            a 
          FROM 
            my_table 
          WHERE 
            num = '987535'
        )
      )
    ), 
    '#'
  ) 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  num != '987535';
```

Expected result:

> 1,295.17

Actual result:

> 1,295

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format  see the examples in the MySQL Reference Manual

Comment: Cool. Thanks Bro. It worked